# Query in Django table intermediate

Tags: django, django-models

I am developing my app in Django 1.10 in which I have the following models:

```
class House(models.Model):
    code = models.IntegerField()
    ......

class Appliance(models.Model):
    code = models.IntegerField()
    ........

class House_appliance(models.Model):
    house = models.Foreignkey(House)
    appliance = models.Foreignkey(Appliance)
```

I want to make a query, where I can know all the homes that have a device in common.
It may be simple but I could not do the query.

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

```
from .models import House_appliance

houses = House.objects.filter(appliance_id = name_of_the_appliance)
```

That will return a queryset of all the objects from House_appliance that have an appliance equal to whatever you choose. Double check to make sure that the field names are right. Look in the actual database for that.

Also, you might want to consider renaming your model to HouseAppliance. It's common practice per the Python/Django style guide.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Appliance that code is 'ABC'

```
house = House_appliance.objects.values('appliance_id', flat=True).filter(house__code='ABC')
all_house = House.objects.filter(pk__in=house)
```

So Here `all_house` var will return all house that have same Appliance

Answer (score 0):

Import the model class you're performing the query on:

`from models import House_appliances`

Perform the query on that model class:

`matchedHouses = House_appliances.objects.filter(appliance=SomeApplianceObject).house`

Where `matchedHouses` is the houses that share the appliance object `SomeApplianceObject`.

`.filter(appliance=SomeApplianeObject)` finds all the objects of that criteria, in this case the Foreign Key appliance.

`.house` accesses the Foreign Key `house` object